# Javascript Get Multiple Substrings Within One String

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, substring

how to get multiple occurences of words in a string. I've tried multiple functions but with no success. I know I can get back the first true value using some() method as below.

```
       var keyword_array = ["Trap","Samples","WAV","MIDI","Loops"];
        function validateContentKeywords(content,keyword){
                keyword.some(function(currentValue,index){

                     console.log(currentValue + " ");

                     return content.indexOf(currentValue) >= 0;         
                });          
        }
     // Outputs --> Trap Samples
       if(validateContentKeywords("Beat Loops WAV Trap Samples Dog Cat MIDI",keyword_array)){
                console.log("Matches");     
        }
    // What I Want is --> Trap,Samples,MIDI,Loops
```

The above function only outputs 2 occurences and I want it to output all of the matching values at the same time such as --> Trap,Samples,MIDI,Loops.
Is there a way to get multiple occurences of words in a string at the same time?

UPDATED:: The solution that helped me out is below

```
           function Matches(value){
                return "Beat Loops WAV Trap Samples Dog Cat MIDI".indexOf(value) !== -1;
           }
           var keyword_array = ["Trap","Samples","WAV","MIDI","Loops"].filter(Matches);
            document.write(keyword_array);
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that code outputs "Trap Samples", because [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) returns a Boolean... Also, [don't use `document.write`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/215552) for, well, anything...

Comment: Your question has the es6 tag, so I guess you could just use the string's include method instead of defining your own. Please, check out my answer to this question. It is really as easy as it gets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for the [`filter` Array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) that returns an array of the matched elements, instead of an boolean value whether some matched.

Comment: @ Bergi, Just what I wanted! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```js
var keyword_array = ["Trap", "Samples", "WAV", "MIDI", "Loops"];

function validateContentKeywords(content, keyword) {
  var words = content.split(' '); //split the given string
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (keyword.indexOf(words[i]) > -1) { //check if actually iterated word from string is in the provided keyword array
      document.write(words[i] + " "); //if it is, write it to the document
    };
  }
}

validateContentKeywords("Beat Loops WAV Trap Samples Dog Cat MIDI", keyword_array);
```

Comment: good solution, but I would rather use the filter function because of its simplicity. Thanks

Comment: @TitusShoats Actually this is the easiest solution possible. And about Bergi's answer, how does this information helps you out with your problem? Drop your working `filter` solution into your question.

Comment: Nope, using `filter` is the straightforward way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it would be this:

```
keyword_array.filter(keyword => searchString.includes(keyword));
```

You can learn more about `filter` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). I highly recommend learning about how to use `map`, `reduce` and `filter`. They are your best friends.